# When starting Dropbox IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and downloaded Dropbox from Nautilus, but it will not start.  When I enter `dropbox start` into the command line it returns this error.

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.6.6/futures-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt

I've tried entering `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist`
which I read fixed an error with the recent release but it didn't change anything.

Comment: How did you install dropbox?. There is no /var/lib/dropbox on my computer. Did you follow some internet guide?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same problem! Just made a new Ubuntu 14.02 installation today. Updated and upgraded the full system to latest patches. Then I installed Dropbox via:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

Got the following error message:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.6.6/futures-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt

Fixed the problem by:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus-dropbox
```

And then download and install Dropbox manually.
https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: Appears like Dropbox broke for a lot of people. This solution worked for me as well.

Comment: This solution did not work with me. I opened a thread about it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31399266/54964 I do not have *nautilus-dropbox* but */usr/bin/dropbox*.

Answer (score 13):

Simply run this command to correct the access rights (for version 3.6.6 and 64-bit)

```
sudo chmod +r /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.6.6/futures-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
```

If the version of Dropbox is different, then adapt the path. (Thx [@rauljosepalma](https://askubuntu.com/users/189510/rauljosepalma))

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This is the real correct answer, no reinstall need. But my dropbox version was not exactly the same, so I copy pasted the correct path from the error message.

Comment: @rauljosepalma Thank you, I have improved my answer. =)

Comment: I have no dropbox fies in `/var/lib/` but instead the binary at `/usr/bin/dropbox` but no idea where files. Do you know where the dropbox files can be? How did you find the path?

Comment: @Masi `find /var/lib/ -iname "*dropbox*"`

Comment: @A.B. I get this */var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.list
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_Release.gpg
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-i386_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_Release
/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages*. Any idea which one should I choose to alter the permissions?